# System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException 2022

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Iam trying to edit information from a table in my database. I can insert the information into the table, but when I try to edit that info, I got the following error message. Any help? please

System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

This is my controller Edit: I got the error in the " context.SaveChanges(); " line

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Editar(int id)
        {
            Cafeteria_POSEntities context = new Cafeteria_POSEntities();
            Faculty empleado = context.Faculties.Single(x => x.Employee_ID == id); 
            ViewBag.Meal_Plan = GetPlanesSelect();
            return View(empleado);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Editar")]
        public ActionResult Editar(Faculty empleado)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Cafeteria_POSEntities context = new Cafeteria_POSEntities();    
                context.Entry(empleado).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(empleado);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'DbEntityValidationException' is an exception that suggests problems with the data you are trying to insert/update in your context/database. I cannot see here because there is not provided input data or the table in your database, but I would say that you either, have a wrong data type for some property, some property might be null which is not allowed, or maybe breaking some primary/foreign key rules.